# Yii2 - download corrupted file

Tags: php, yii, yii2, xlsx, yii2-advanced-app

I am working on existing products and i am trying to resolve problem with downloading xlsx file.
When i download file through file manager, file is allright. But when i download file through Yii app, the file is corrupted.

Here is my code

```
public function actionCallLog($hash, $filename)
    {
        var_dump(
            $hash, $filename
        );

        ignore_user_abort(true);
        set_time_limit(0);
        

        $path = "/var/www/html/uploads/call_log/".$hash.'/';

        $dl_file= basename($filename).'.xlsx';
        if (!file_exists($path.$dl_file)) {
            $dl_file= basename($filename).'.csv';
        }
        $fullPath = $path.$dl_file;

        if ($fd = fopen ($fullPath, "r"))
        {

            $fsize = filesize($fullPath);
            $path_parts = pathinfo($fullPath);
            $ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);
            switch ($ext)
            {
                case "xlsx":
                header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
                header("Content-type: application/xlsx");
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");
                break;
                case "csv":
                header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
                header("Content-type: application/csv");
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");
                break;
                // add more headers for other content types here
                default;
                header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
                header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
                header("Content-Disposition: filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");
                break;
            }
            header("Content-length: $fsize");
            header("Cache-control: private");
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Pragma: public');
            while(!feof($fd))
            {
                $buffer = fread($fd, 2048);
                echo $buffer;
            }
        }
        fclose ($fd);
        exit;
    }
```

Does anybody know where can be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Try header `Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`

Comment: Still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try turning off all the header instructions (and also the "echo $buffer;" as that might be a lot on screen) and see if any warnings or errors is printed on screen when opening the url for the file download.

If the corrupted file has a size, your code might actually give a warning or generate other output which will become part of the file because it is also echo'ed. Obviously that extra plain text output by your code would turn your correct xlsx into a corrupt file. You might be able to get that text by opening your corrupted file in a text-editor as it would show in there in plain text (probably at the start).

Answer (score 0):

try add  the response format

```
\Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_RAW;
```

and for xlsx the content type should be

```
'application/vnd.ms-excel'
```

Answer (score 0):

Right before your first `header` call add:

```
ob_end_clean();  // clear out anything that may have already been output
```

Basically, any echoing leads into the stream that might corrupt your sheet. And it has to be cleared.

Answer Courtesy: [Please check here for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56900314/4476745)